# How to prove the inverse of an inverse of a group element is the element itself without $a + a^{-1} = a^{-1} + a$?

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering how one would go about proving the inverse of an inverse of a group element is the element itself, but without being able to use either $a + a^{-1}  = a^{-1} + a$ or $0+a=a+0$?

If we only have associativity and $a + a^{-1} = 0$ (that is, if we know $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of a), I just don't see how I'd show $a = (a^{-1})^{-1}$. Any suggestions?

I'm really puzzled by this one, I have to say. I can show the equality if we have $0+a=a+0$ for all a in the group, but not without.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you sure the result is even true with these weak assumptions?

Comment: In fact, I'm not quite sure what your assumptions even are. You've mentioned some things you don't want to use; can you tell us exactly what things you *are* using?

Comment: I think one can prove that the second inverse of an element is the same as the element under fairly weak sounding hypotheses (I'm thinking only being allowed same side identity and inverse), but I agree with @ChrisEagle that we need more information about what is available.

Comment: @ChrisEagle, the assumptions are stated in the second paragraph, i.e. there's only associativity and $a + a^{-1} = 0$ if $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of a. Note that we are NOT given that if $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of a, that a is then the inverse of $a^{-1}$ nor $a^{-1} + a = 0$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle that's why I'm so confused by this. This, I think, is supposed to be an easy question, but without either of the two additional assumptions (which we actually have to prove further on), I can't see how to go about it.

Comment: @peoplepower could you elaborate on that? I made a slight edit, but the second paragraph includes all of the assumptions.

Comment: In my answer, I only used that $0$ is a left unit and that each element has a left inverse. Were those not the conditions you wanted?

Comment: Why are you mixing up notations, using $+$ for the group operation but $a^{-1}$ for inverse? Usually, we either go with $(-a)$ and $+$ and $a^{-1}$ and $\cdot$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's how the question was formulated.

Comment: Then @Ryker, whoever did it either tried to make some very particular point or else he loves very messy notation...or he's simply wrong. As Thomas told you, the notation $\,a^{-1}\,$ is usually reserved for *multiplicative* inverse, whereas the *additive* inverse is almost always denoted $\,-a\,$ . Is this from a book? Because if it is you can try to gives us a link to it and to the page, or copy and paste the particular page.

Comment: @DonAntonio, it isn't from a book, and I realize the notation is clumsy. But that's what was given, and I didn't want to change anything.

Comment: @Ryker Do you see how that too is not helpful? By saying where it did not come from just makes the whole scenario more fantastic

Comment: @peoplepower, it's from a homework, but I can only speak to the instructor personally in the coming days, as he doesn't answer e-mails. I just wanted to get this done earlier than that.

Comment: Ryker, then something seems to be pretty wrong in your question: your mixing two notation for two different things, and you're talking of a group, with *one* single operation...if it is additive notation $\,+\,$, why then it is used the multiplicative notation $\,a^{-1}\,$ to denote an *additive* inverse? If there's no further explanation I cannot but deduce that someone made a huge mistake here...

Comment: Yet, if *Still* your instructor (or your whole mathematics department), for some reason, uses to mix these usually pretty different notations, my answer below, I think, still holds mutatis mutandis.

Comment: @DonAntonio + is just an operation, not necessarily addition (I've edited that out of the original post to avoid confusion), and I agree the notation is confusing, but it is what it is. And we don't have uniqueness of inverses, at least I don't think so. I also don't see how you'd apply your argument then (I didn't downvote it, though). Maybe now you guys see why this is so confusing and why I turned to you with such an elementary question.

Comment: @Ryker I'm sure the question is elementary, but in the one place you state that we have a group; in the second, you require that we pretend it is not a group. This just does not sound like a real question (as in a question that anybody should be required to devote thought to).

Comment: @peoplepower, when you say we pretend it is not a group are you talking about the two assumptions that you are _not_ allowed to use? If yes, I agree, but if not, what exactly are you getting at?

Comment: @Ryker Yes, we start with an object, we learn it is a group, then we are supposed to prove aspects of the group as if we do not know parts of the axioms defining a group. We needed to have a group at some point, or Chris Eagle's answer would apply; so what do we know about the group before our amnesia struck?

Comment: @Ryker So let me see if I understand your question, putting the notation issues aside: we're looking at a set with an operation, but the set is *not* necessarily a group under this operation.  I think you assume the operation is associative, and presumably you have an identity element since you use the symbol 0 and you talk about inverses.  It's unclear if you're stating that *every* element has a right inverse, or just a particular element.  You then ask if the right inverse is also a left inverse?

Comment: @peoplepower As far as I can see, we only know closure, associativity, $a+0=a$ (but not $0+a=a$) and that every element has an inverse, i.e. for each a, there exists $a^{-1}$ s.t. $a+a^{-1}=0$ (but not $a^{-1}+a=0$).

Comment: @Ryker OK, that follows the conditions of a classical result. What you wrote here should be your second paragraph.

Comment: Ryker, one of the "axioms" of group theory requires "uniqueness" (or stems from the other axioms), both of inverse and of unit element, so if you have a group you have uniqueness...or else, how did you people define "group"?!  ANd I know + is only an operation, the umbersome thing is that you mix it with with a notation from a different operation.

Comment: I think i understand, finally!!, Ryker's question (if I'm right you then need to edit it as it is very confusing now): you have a set with a binary operation (closure) and with right unit element and right inverse element (with you awful notations), and you want to prove both the unit element and the inverse are *also* left ones and we thus have a group ...did I hit the nail on the head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we need to assume that $0 + a = a$ for all $a$ and that for all $a$ there is an $a^{-1}$ such that $a^{-1} + a = 0$ (or of course in the other order, but we cannot just assume those two conditions with the order switched in one of them).

Under these assumptions, let us check that $a + a^{-1} = 0$. We get $a^{-1} + a + a^{-1} = 0 + a^{-1} = a^{-1}$ but we can cancel $a^{-1}$ on the left dues to our assumptions, so we get $a + a^{-1} = 0$ as we wanted.

Comment: Why would we be able to cancel $a^{-1}$ on the left?

Comment: Because we are assuming that each element has a left inverse.

Comment: But of course :) I got confused because my assumptions in regards to "handedness" were the opposite of yours, and it just didn't click. I hang my head in shame...

Answer (score 4):

The claim does not follow from the assumptions you are using. For example, suppose $X$ is any set with at least two elements (one of which is called 0), and let $+$ be defined by $x+y=0$ for every $x$ and $y$, and $^{-1}$ be defined by $x^{-1}=0$ for every $x$. Then $+$ is associative, and $x+x^{-1}=0$ clearly holds for every $x$, but $(x^{-1})^{-1}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hypotheses that the operation (which I will refer to as juxtaposition) is closed, associative, and satisfies the properties that there is a right identity (I will call this 1) and a right inverse is guaranteed for each element of the set $G$, it is known that $G$ is a group. We are interested in the seemingly smaller result that $a=(a^{-1})^{-1}$ for all $a\in G$.

For any $a$, we compute $$a^{-1}a=a^{-1}a1=a^{-1}a(a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1})=(a^{-1}1)(a^{-1})^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=1$$ where the associative law was used to cancel middle terms. This proves that the inverse $a^{-1}$ applies to both sides of a. In particular, $a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=1=(a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}$, so we can now prove the desired statement.$$a=a1=a(a^{-1}a)=1a=((a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1})a=(a^{-1})^{-1}$$

Notice that in doing so, we prove that $a1=a=1a$; all we did was show that $G$ is a group and do the usual proof of the fact that the inverse of the inverse recovers the original element.

Comment: Of course, in the last sentence I mean that "the inverse has order 2 in a group" instead of "idempotent".

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Sorry I didn't choose your answer as accepted, I realized Tobias was also right, and since he posted first I felt obliged to choose his. I actually like your approach better (i.e. it aligns better with what I'd have done), so please don't be offended. Anyway, thanks for all the help, I guess I was really confused that the things you guys proved first were those that were given to us as needing proof in later parts of the question, with my original question being the first one. But I guess we've established you can't prove that without proving what you guys did, no?

Comment: @Ryker Thanks for your kind remarks. I don't get worked up over accepts so don't worry. :) As for the final remark I do not believe a single sequence of equalities will prove more than what we did. In particular, I would be surprised if there was a sequence of equalities linking $a$ and $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ without needing to draw intermediate conclusions along the way.